# QTableWidgetItem performance

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidgetitem

I put some text in QTableWidget's cells, like this:

```
tableWidget.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(myText))
```

and scrolling through table is very slow (1fps or less) over rows which have QTableWidgetItems with myText length over 5000 (+/-1000)

I need  `tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()` and I thought it has to have something with rows height so I tried `tableWidget.setRowHeight(i,1000)` for those rows. Text in them was cuted and I have to resize row's height in order to see all text, but still, when scrolling over those rows, performances are very low.

Is there some quick solution for this? I would not like to use setCellWidget if possible.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no other solution,I had to put text that has length over 5000 in `QTextEdit` and use `setCellWidget`. Scrolling table is not slow anymore. Reason I didn't put them all in `QTextEdit`s is that Windows7 can show limited number of GUI elements (<20000 I think) and I have 10 columns x up to 100000 rows.